# What is the use of pip's --user option on Windows?

Tags: python, pip

I'm confused with the `--user` option of `pip` on Windows. It seems that on Windows packages will always be installed to my home directory (`C:\Users\{username}\...`) regardless of the presence of `--user`, while on Linux packages will be installed to a global location if `--user` is omitted:

```
C:\>pip3 install pyyaml
Collecting pyyaml
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/19/53c041b8719eaf88ce1cdb51bea1c5a2844433e79c23a2a8aeeaa0e27fd8/PyYAML-5.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: pyyaml
Successfully installed pyyaml-5.1.1

C:\>pip3 show pyyaml
Name: PyYAML
Version: 5.1.1
Summary: YAML parser and emitter for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml
Author: Kirill Simonov
Author-email: xi@resolvent.net
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\{username}\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

C:\>pip3 uninstall pyyaml
Uninstalling PyYAML-5.1.1:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\{username}\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\_yaml.cp37-win32.pyd
    c:\users\{username}\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyyaml-5.1.1.dist-info\*
    c:\users\{username}\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\yaml\*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled PyYAML-5.1.1

C:\>pip3 install --user pyyaml
Collecting pyyaml
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/19/53c041b8719eaf88ce1cdb51bea1c5a2844433e79c23a2a8aeeaa0e27fd8/PyYAML-5.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: pyyaml
Successfully installed pyyaml-5.1.1

C:\>pip3 show pyyaml
Name: PyYAML
Version: 5.1.1
Summary: YAML parser and emitter for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml
Author: Kirill Simonov
Author-email: xi@resolvent.net
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\{username}\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

All the commands above were run under a normal user, not Administrator.

So what is the use of pip's `--user` option on Windows? Is it necessary to use `--user` option whenever I install packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed confusing how the Windows Python installer handles install location with default settings (which you most probably used).

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html), when you run the installer and just click "Install Now":

> - You will *not* need to be an administrator (unless a system update for the C Runtime Library is required or you install the Python Launcher for Windows for all users)
> - Python will be installed into your user directory
> - The Python Launcher for Windows will be installed according to the option at the bottom of the first page.

Now, the option for the Python Launcher is *also* selected by default. This means, if your user account is in the "Administrator" group (which it typically is), Python (`python.exe`) will be installed in your `%LocalAppData%` directory (just as you have observed). However, the installer will still present you with a UAC prompt to confirm you have admin privileges, as it also wants to install the Python Launcher (`py.exe`). You end up with a local, "just for me" Python installation in your user directory, though for some intangible reason the Launcher is installed "for all users".

If you really want to have a system-wide Python installation, you need to select "Customize installation" on the first screen of the installer, then click "Next", and check "Install for all users" — which is not checked otherwise. The install location will then default to your `%ProgramFiles%` directory, usually `C:\Program Files`.

When you do user-installs with `pip`, it will put the packages in your `%AppData%` directory, which is `AppData\Roaming` in your user profile (as you have also observed). This is so that when you have a "roaming" account on a domain network, your personally installed packages follow you around, no matter from which computer on the network you log in. Obviously, that computer would have to have a system-wide Python installation "for all users" — of the Python *interpreter*, not the nearly irrelevant Python *Launcher*. This is where the default behavior, described above, makes absolutely *zero* sense, as you wouldn't be able to run the Python interpreter installed locally in some *other* user's profile when you log on to their computer.

On top of that, if you actually *do* use your profile to "roam" the domain network, all those `--user` packages, which, more likely than not, comprise thousands of files, will slow down the log-in process: every one of those files has to be sync'ed between domain storage and the local computer.

Bottom line: If you want to set this up properly, customize your installation to make sure it's installed in some directory that is *in fact* accessible to *all* users. Personally, I like to put it in `C:\programs\Python`, as I can then `pip install` anything for everyone and don't even need an elevated prompt — which one would for writing to `C:\Program Files`. Then again, requiring an elevated prompt may be advisable, depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If you had been logged in as the Administrator when the package was installed without the `--user` option, then the package would have been installed in the Python installation's `Lib/site-packages` directory and made available to all user accounts. If, instead you had used the `--user` option, then, as you have seen, the package would be installed "locally" and only be visible to the Administrator's account.

Comment: But the fact is that I was not logged in as Administrator but a normal user.

Comment: Read my answer again. You asked what is the point of '--user'. If you are logged on as a non-administrator it does not make much of a difference if you use this option or not. **But, it does make a big difference if you are logged on as an administrator**. Without `--user` the package becomes visible to all accounts, with `--user` it is visible just to the currently logged in administrator account.